# How to import data from external webpage connection in MS Access like excel has Data- WebPage

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Like excel has Data=>From Web to import a table in webpage in excel. How can I achieve this in MS Access?  I want to data in table in external web page into the MS Access Table. Just Like we can in excel. 
I don't want to use any intermediate excel to import data in Access but direct 
 external html page data into Access.

I want to import the option chain from NSE India into MS Access.
The external webdata is Option chain from NSE india like in URL:
https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10003&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17

This was done in Excel but I want to do it in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this; Access can get the table from the downloaded file, but it will be confused by the double-line headers. It can ignore one line but not two, thus the headers' second line will be read as data scrambling the real data.

Excel just does a better job isolating the table with its headers and values. Your best option, in my opinion, will be to automate Excel, using it to retrieve the page and build the table. Then, from Access, link the prepared worksheet holding the table.

Alternatively, use the function *DownloadFile* found in my project at GitHub: [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl), link the file, and create a query (using the linked file as source) where you clean up and convert the retrieved data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years too late, but there's a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/4zG6e6ntYd8) about this.

This is a pretty specific case, but it links to a Wikipedia table. I would try to apply the website mentioned at the top, but it's no longer working. This should get you started as an example.

It basically looks for all tables and then within the list, looks for a specific table name identifier, and then uses it as the data source.

```
Sub ImportWikiPresidentsLog()
Dim httpRequest As Object
Dim html As Object
Dim allTables As Object
Dim table As Object
Dim row As Object
Dim cell As Object
Dim rowNum As Integer
Dim colNum As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim tableName As String

tableName = "WikiPresidentsLog"

' Initialize HTTP request
Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
httpRequest.Open "GET", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_presidents_of_the_United_States", False
httpRequest.send

' Check the status of the request
If httpRequest.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "Web page could not be retrieved. Status: " & httpRequest.Status
    Exit Sub
End If

' Create an HTML Document object
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText

' Get all tables in the document
Set allTables = html.getElementsByTagName("table")

' Find the first table with the class "wikitable"
Dim foundTable As Boolean
foundTable = False
For i = 0 To allTables.Length - 1
    If InStr(allTables(i).className, "wikitable") > 0 Then
        Set table = allTables(i)
        foundTable = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

If Not foundTable Then
    MsgBox "Table with the class 'wikitable' not found."
    Exit Sub
End If

' Open the database
Set db = CurrentDb

' Delete the WikiPresidentsLog table if it exists
If DCount("*", "MSysObjects", "Name = '" & tableName & "' And Type In (1, 4)") > 0 Then
    db.Execute "DROP TABLE " & tableName, dbFailOnError
End If

' Create the WikiPresidentsLog table with an additional DateTimeStamp field
db.Execute "CREATE TABLE " & tableName & " (" _
            & "ID AutoIncrement PRIMARY KEY, " _
            & "RowNum Integer, " _
            & "ColNum Integer, " _
            & "CellText Memo, " _
            & "DateTimeStamp DateTime)", dbFailOnError

' Open a recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(tableName, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

' Iterate through each row of the table
rowNum = 0
For Each row In table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    colNum = 0
    For Each cell In row.cells
        ' Insert cell data into the log table
        rs.AddNew
        rs!rowNum = rowNum
        rs!colNum = colNum
        rs!CellText = cell.innerText
        rs!DateTimeStamp = Now() ' Add the current date and time
        rs.Update

        colNum = colNum + 1
    Next cell
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
Next row

' Clean up
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Set httpRequest = Nothing
Set html = Nothing

MsgBox "Data logged to " & tableName & " table."
```

End Sub